# Prevent view dismissing after the request access to the AVCaptureDevice

Tags: swift3, avcapturedevice

How can we prevent the view from going to the previous view after user clicks OK button on camera access prompt? Here is our code:

```
func RequestCameraAccess() {
    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) -> Void in
        if granted == true {
            print("User Granted")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.Cam();
            }
        } else {
            print("User Rejected")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image1.isHidden = true
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code from "self.Cam()" method pls

Comment: in my code I commented out self.cam function call, and facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that in the moment of camera access granting the following method occurs:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {}
```

In my application I had logic to move to home screen in case of inactivity for a certain amount of time.

Thanks anyway.